# Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in PHP y SQL SERVER

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, php8

tengo un problema ya que en un sistema de encuesta al momento de hacer el insert no hay ningun problema, sin embargo al momento de ir al apartado para responder me aparece el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el codigo que estoy utilizando

```
<?php

    require "../conexion.php";

    $id_encuesta = $_GET['id_encuesta'];
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM sistema_encuestasv1.preguntas WHERE id_encuesta = '$id_encuesta'";
    $respuesta2 = sqlsrv_query($con, $query2);

    $query3 = "SELECT encuestas.titulo, encuestas.descripcion, preguntas.id_pregunta, preguntas.id_encuesta, preguntas.id_tipo_pregunta 
        FROM sistema_encuestasv1.preguntas
        INNER JOIN sistema_encuestasv1.encuestas
        ON preguntas.id_encuesta = encuestas.id_encuesta
        WHERE preguntas.id_encuesta = '$id_encuesta'";
    $respuesta3 = sqlsrv_query($con, $query3);
    $row3 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($respuesta3);


 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Favicon - FIS -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../imagenes/Logo-fis.png">


  <title>Responder</title>
</head>
<body>


    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)">Sistema de Encuestas</a>
     
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navb">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    

      <!--NAVBAR-->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navb">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" style="color: #fff">
          
            <?php   
            session_start();
                if (isset($_SESSION['u_usuario']) && isset($_SESSION['id_usuario'])) {
                  echo "Bienvenido " . $_SESSION['u_usuario'] . "\t";
                  echo "<a href='../cerrar_sesion.php' class='btn btn-danger' style='margin-left: 10px'>Cerrar Sesión</a>";
                } else {
                  header("Location: ../index.php");
                }
           ?>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
  
    <div class="container text-center">
        <hr /> 
        <h1><?php echo $row3['titulo'] ?></h1>
        <p><?php echo $row3['descripcion'] ?></p>

        <form action="procesar.php" method="Post" autocomplete="off">


        <input type="hidden" id="id_encuesta" name="id_encuesta" value="<?php echo $id_encuesta ?>" />

        <hr />
        <?php

            $i = 1; 
            while (($row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($respuesta2))) {

            $id = $row2['id_pregunta'];

            $query = "SELECT preguntas.id_pregunta, preguntas.titulo, preguntas.id_tipo_pregunta, opciones.id_opcion, opciones.valor
                FROM sistema_encuestasv1.opciones
                INNER JOIN sistema_encuestasv1.preguntas
                ON preguntas.id_pregunta = opciones.id_pregunta
                WHERE preguntas.id_pregunta = $id
                ORDER BY opciones.id_pregunta, opciones.id_opcion";

            $respuesta = sqlsrv_query($con, $query);

         ?>
            <div class="container col-md-12">
            <h4><?php echo  $row2['titulo'] ?></h4>
            
        <?php 
            while (($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($respuesta))) {

         ?>
            <div class="radio">
              <label><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="<?php echo $row['id_pregunta'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['id_opcion'] ?>" required> <?php echo $row['valor'] ?></label>
            </div>

        
        <?php   
            }
            $i++;
        }
         ?>
            </div>
        <br/>
        <input type="hidden" name="id_encuesta" value="<?php echo $id_encuesta ?>">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Responder">
        </form>
        <br/>

        <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-primary">Regresar</a>
    </div>



    
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="../js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

porque sucede eso? que puedo hacer?

Comment: Primero... tienes repetido el `input` (hidden) con nombre `"id_encuesta"` aunque en uno con id y en otro sin él. Y después... Das por sentado que siempre te pasan el parámetro id_encuesta en la URL (con `GET`), y que ese id existe en la base de datos, porque ya asignas el resultado a `$row3`y después accedes al campo `'titulo'` y otros sin saber si la consulta ha generado filas o no. Si por ejemplo buscas la encuesta 54 y no existe, ya te saltará ese error.

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurren 2 opciones:

**1.-** No estas pasando ningun parametro a través del método GET, que sería algo así:**TodaTuDireccion\responder.php?id_usuario=4.**

**2.-** El Id que mandas a través del método GET no existe.

Espero te sirva de ayuda.